# data type mismatch error when using ORDER BY

Tags: android, sqlite

I've got an android app using a local sqlite database.

```
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
```

when I run this query I get my Cursor over rows with pid equal to id, as desired:

```
mDb.query(true, PT_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_PID, KEY_TID}, 
    KEY_PID+" = "+id, null, null, null, null, null);
```

when I run the following query, aiming to get that same result set, ordered by pid I get "**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: datatype mismatch**"

```
mDb.query(true, PT_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_PID, KEY_TID}, 
    KEY_PID+" = "+id, null, null, null, null, KEY_PID+" DESC");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It looks like you got just a little mixed up.  According to the [`SQLiteDatabase.query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) documentation, the last argument is the `LIMIT` clause.  The second to last is the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
Cursor query (boolean distinct, 
            String table, 
            String[] columns, 
            String selection, 
            String[] selectionArgs, 
            String groupBy, 
            String having, 
            String orderBy, // <-- ORDER BY
            String limit)
```

**EDIT**

But, there is also another [`SQLiteDatabase.query`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) where `ORDER BY` would be last

```
Cursor query (String table, 
            String[] columns, 
            String selection, 
            String[] selectionArgs, 
            String groupBy, 
            String having, 
            String orderBy)
```

Comment: In the documentation there also looks to be a version: SQLiteDatabase.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy) <-- notice one field (the limit) is missing

Comment: That's wrong, mentioned doc also gives the following call `query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)`.

Comment: @2ndGAB: actually, the method you mention is the same one that Dandre mentions and Sandip uses in his answer, and isn't the one in Bee's question. Note they have different arities (7 vs 9) and yours doesn't take a boolean (`distinct`, from the method used in the question).

Comment: Isn't this "KEY_PID+" = "+id" vulnerable to SQL injection? I mean if you do this with Strings..

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me

```
String filter = MySQLiteHelper.JOB_ID + "=" + Integer.toString(jobID);
String orderBy =  MySQLiteHelper.LOG_TIME + " DESC";
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.LOG_TABLE_NAME, logTableColumns,
        filter, null, null, null, orderBy);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
KEY_PID + " = " + "'" + id + "'"
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Orderby is the second last parameter in the query;
your query would be like this

```
mDb.query(true, PT_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_PID, KEY_TID}, 
    KEY_PID+" = "+id, null, null, null, KEY_PID+" DESC", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood your problem, try this.

```
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_PID, KEY_TID};
    String where = KEY_PID + " = " + Integer.toString(id);
    String orderBy = KEY_PID + " DESC";

    Cursor cursor = mDb.query(PT_TABLE, columns, where, null, null, null, orderBy);
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue